# Perl: Dice roll "fix" to translate 2-8, 5-8, to 2d4, 1d4+3

Tags: perl, dice

I am trying to do some importing of data that uses different dice roll text. For example you'll have 2-4, 2-12, 5-8, 2-5. I am trying to write a translator that will convert them to proper dice rolls. What I have so far will translate it but I end up with some odd rolls. For example on the 5-8 it comes up with 5d1+3. With other things like 2-8 it will give me a reasonable 2d4. I'm trying to figure out how to make it ALWAYS use "real" dice.

Currently I am using this perl script. You simply pass it the dice string you want to fix and it returns what it thinks is the right roll. My problem is I can't think of how to limit the dice "sides" to only these 2,3,4,6,8,12,20 sides.

```
# turn 2-7 into 1d6+1 or 2-8 into 2d4
sub fix_DiceRolls {
 my($diceRoll) = @_;
 use POSIX;

 if ($diceRoll =~ /^(\d+)(\-)(\d+)\b/i) {
  # 2-5
  #Group 1.     0-1     `2`
  #Group 2.     1-2     `-`
  #Group 3.     2-3     `5`

  my($count) = $1;
  my($size) = $3;

  if ($count == 1) {
   $diceRoll = "$1d$3";
  } else {
    my ($newSize) = $size/$count;
    my ($remainder) = $size % $count;
    my ($round_remainder)   = ceil($remainder);
    my ($round_newSize) = floor($newSize);
    if ($remainder == 0) {
     $diceRoll = $count."d".$newSize;
    } else {
     $diceRoll = $count."d".$round_newSize."+".$round_remainder;
    }

  }

 }

 return $diceRoll;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure this conversion is even correct? Rolling 2d4 for a range of 2-8 gives a nonuniform distribution -- rolls of 2 or 8 will be less common than 5 or 6.

Comment: All I can say is that in the original text when they use "2-8" they mean roll 2 dice that have 4 sides. i.e. 2d4. When I push 2-8 through the script it comes back with 2d4 as a result.

Comment: If "2-8" in the original means 2d4, what does "5-8" mean?  Five dice with ?? sides?

Comment: 5-8 = 1d4+4. The challenge is always to find a range that involves real dice.  And sometimes those real dice get, er, dicey ... 1-3 would be 1d3, which isn't a real die, but can be faked with a d6, and, similarly, 1-2 would be 1d2, or basically a coin toss.  And then 2-4 is either 2d2 or 1d3+1, and you can't tell the difference.  10-40 is either 10d4 or 4d10, again, both valid.

Comment: @Tanktalus 10-40 is not 4d10. 4d10 would  be 4-40

Comment: Also note that 1-10 could be 3d4-2.

Comment: @Nullman sorry, my bad, yes. I had another example that now escapes me where there were some weird possibilities. Regardless, there are many ranges that could result in multiple variations, and some sort of resolution of these possibilities is required. Generally, that means: fewest dice, and no subtractions. Not that subtraction isn't allowed, just isn't usually what is meant.

Comment: @Tanktalus, Re "*1d3, which isn't a real die*", There are three-sided dice.

Comment: @ikegami - well, not one most people have anyway :P

Answer (score 1):

The following might help you. It doesn't know how to do `1d6/2`, but it correctly translates `4-19` to `3d6+1 | 5d4-1`.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw{ say };

my @valid_dice = (4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 20);

sub fix_dice_roll {
    my ($dice_roll) = @_;

    my ($from, $to) = split /-/, $dice_roll;
    my $range = $to - $from + 1;

    my @translations;
    for my $dice (@valid_dice) {
        if (0 == ($range - 1) % ($dice - 1)) {
            my $times = ($range - 1) / ($dice - 1);
            my $plus = sprintf '%+d', $to - $times * $dice;
            $plus = q() if '+0' eq $plus;
            push @translations, [ $dice, $times, $plus ];
        }
    }

    @translations = sort { $a->[1] <=> $b->[1] } @translations;
    return map "$_->[1]d$_->[0]$_->[2]", @translations;
}

say join ' | ', fix_dice_roll($_) while <>;
```

Comment: I added some 2 and 3 to the allowed dice, threw in a few checks to get it to pick certain dice over others (>=4 size and no modifiers/etc).
Thanks for the help!

Comment: You can remove the sort if you have other criteria in place. I just sorted by "times", so the solution with the least number of dice was always first.